# There are some geometric means between

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

There are some geometric means between $\dfrac {1}{2}$ and $16$. If the third mean be $4$, find the number of means between two numbers.  Also find the last mean.

My Attempt 
Let $N$ be the number of geometric means between $\dfrac {1}{2}$ and $16$.
$$a=\dfrac {1}{2}$$
$$b=16$$
Now, 
$$r=(\dfrac {b}{a})^{\dfrac {1}{N+1}}$$
$$r=2^{\dfrac {5}{N+1}}$$

Then, What's next!?

Comment: `the third mean be 4` You need to use this somewhere along the way.

Comment: @ dxiv, using that I got $\textrm N=\dfrac {2}{3}$$.. I think it's wrong

Comment: Doublecheck your calculations. That condition should give the common ratio as $\sqrt[3]{\left(4 / \frac{1}{2}\right)}\,$.

Comment: @ dxiv,  then $N=4$.

Comment: If the common ratio is $2$ and the $3^{rd}$ term is $4$ then $16$ will be the $5^{th}$ term. If what the problem calls the `last mean` is the term just before that then, yes, it would be the $4^{th}\,$.

Comment: @ dxiv,  Last mean is the term preceding the last term

Comment: Then you got it right, that's the $4^{th}$.

Answer (score 2):

The means will be $\dfrac 12r, \dfrac 12r^2, \dfrac 12r^3, \dots, \dfrac 12r^n$ for some $n$. If the third mean is $4$, then

\begin{align}
   \dfrac 12r^3 &= 4\\
   r^3 &= 8 \\
   r &= 2
\end{align}

So the means are $1,2,4,8$